# Where are the source files for my Docker application deployed to ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I built a Dockerized Python/Django application and deployed it to ECS using [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/).

The application is deployed and responsive. But I notice there are some bugs. So to troubleshoot, I SSH'ed the the EC2 instance running the application. I did a `ps` and I can clearly see all my application's processes running. That's good.

However, when I look for my source files and any of the application's log files, I cannot find them anywhere on that instance. I have searched the entire disk thoroughly but those files are nowhere to be found. How is that possible? Where is it running my application from? Does it run it out of the ECR? How can I monitor log files for my application?

Comment: Your code is inside the running container. Use `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` to bash inside docker. You'll find your code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 200 OK suggested, you need to ssh into the docker container to see your application files.

`docker exec -it <container_id> bash`

Also, you can see the logs from the AWS CloudWatch Console itself if you enable the awslogs log driver in the application's ECS Task Definition.